# Show that two embeddings of $M$ into its product are not homotopic

Tags: algebraic-topology

Assume that $M$ is a compact smooth manifold with positive dimension. We have two ways of embedding $M$ into its product with itself. Way I: $ i_1(m) = (m, m)$ and Way II: $i_2(m) = (a, m)$, where $a \in M$. Show that those two maps cannot be homotopic.

If $i_1$ and $i_2$ are homotopic, then I claim $M$ is null homotopic because if $\pi_1 \circ i_1 = id$ and $\pi_1 \circ i_1$ is a constant map. Then it boils down to showing that $M$ cannot be null homotopic. If $M$ is orientable, then its top cohomology is $\mathbb R$, so it cannot be null homotopoic. What if $M$ is not orientable?

Comment: $M$ is certainly a manifold, but why don't you mention this? Is it a topological or a smooth manifold? And $M$ null homotopic means $M$ contractible.

Comment: My apologies and it is assumed to be a smooth manifold.

Comment: You should edit your question..

Comment: Also, there's a typo, it's $\pi_1\circ i_{\bf 2}$ which is a constant map.

Comment: Maybe he means that if i_1 is homotopic to i_2 then pi_1 of i_1 is homotopic to pi_1 of i_2 which is a constant map.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the following result which shows that the homology mod 2  of a non orientable compact manifold is not trivial.

[Homology Groups of Non Orientable Manifold](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2926067/homology-groups-of-non-orientable-manifold)

Answer (score 2):

You have to show that a compact manifold $M$ cannot be contractible. Each contractible manifold is simply connected, and such manifolds are orientable.